# For YouTube video, how to automatically display interactive transcript?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

YouTube supports interactive-transcripts, using both machine-generated and user-uploaded transcripts.  This is very useful for hearings, lectures, speeches, and educational videos where a visitor might want to read along or jump around.  For example in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY3U2GXhz44

The visitor can click on "...More" and then "Transcript" to view the interactive-transcript.

How does a video owner make that hidden feature automatically open for visitors?  I cannot find any documented method for doing that through the API for either embed or linked videos.  Is there an undocumented method in the API, or a URL parameter like "&action-panel-transcript=true" that works the way I'd expect it to?

Comment: Unfortunately, I also cannot find any references regarding this using the API. You may file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) for this.

Comment: This is not a simple option, but the answer to this question explains how to do this with YT's API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843796/how-to-youtube-transcript-with-api-captions-download

Answer (score 0):

As for url parameter, you can try adding &cc_load_policy=1 behind the rel=0 if it's an embedded video or &yt:cc=on at the end of the url if it's a link to the video.

Source: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/force-subtitles-embedded-youtube-video/

Comment: This enables captioning, but does not address the video's transcript, which is a separate feature.